# Adding a play again option to python game

Tags: python-2.7

I'm working on making a game for my programming class using python. I don't know how to give the option to the player again when they lose, or quit the game. I am using python 2.7. This is the code for my game:

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *


# set up pygame
pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()

# set up the window
WINDOWWIDTH = 1000
WINDOWHEIGHT = 500
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Dankest Memes')

# set up the colors
PINK = (223, 61, 163)
TEXTCOLOR = (223, 61, 163)



def waitForPlayerToPressKey():
 while True:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == QUIT:
             terminate()
         if event.type == KEYDOWN:
             if event.key == K_ESCAPE: # pressing escape quits
                 terminate()
             return

def terminate():
 while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
             terminate()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE: # pressing escape quits
                 terminate()
            return

def drawText(text, font, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, TEXTCOLOR)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)
TEXTCOLOR = (255,250,250)

Score=4

 # set up fonts
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)
myscore=4

# set up the block data structure
file = 'score.txt'
player = pygame.Rect(300, 100, 40, 40)
playerImage = pygame.image.load('player.png')
playerStretchedImage = pygame.transform.scale(playerImage, (40, 40))
foodImage = pygame.image.load('meme.png')
foods = []
for i in range(20):
    foods.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH - 20), random.randint(0, WINDOWHEIGHT - 20), 20, 20))

foodCounter = 0
NEWFOOD = 40

baddie = pygame.Rect(300, 100, 40, 40)
baddieImage = pygame.image.load('baddie.png')
baddieStretchedImage = pygame.transform.scale(baddieImage, (40, 40))
baddies = []
for i in range(20):
    baddies.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH - 20), random.randint(0, WINDOWHEIGHT - 20), 20, 20))

baddieCounter = 0
NEWBADDIE = 120

# set up keyboard variables
moveLeft = False
moveRight = False
moveUp = False
moveDown = False

MOVESPEED = 6

# set up music
pickUpSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('pickup.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.load('background.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
musicPlaying = True

# show the "Start" screen
drawText('Dankest Memes', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
drawText('Press any key to start.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 50, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
drawText('Move with WASD or the arrow keys.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 50, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 100)
drawText('Collect green Pepes to get points.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 50, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 150)
drawText('Avoid the chickens.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 50, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 200)
pygame.display.update()
waitForPlayerToPressKey()


# run the game loop
while True:
    # check for the QUIT event
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            # change the keyboard variables
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                moveRight = False
                moveLeft = True
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                moveLeft = False
                moveRight = True
            if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                moveDown = False
                moveUp = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                moveUp = False
                moveDown = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                moveLeft = False
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                moveRight = False
            if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                moveUp = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                moveDown = False
            if event.key == ord('x'):
                player.top = random.randint(0, WINDOWHEIGHT - player.height)
                player.left = random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH - player.width)
            if event.key == ord('m'):
                if musicPlaying:
                    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                else:
                    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
                musicPlaying = not musicPlaying

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            foods.append(pygame.Rect(event.pos[0] - 10, event.pos[1] - 10, 20, 20))

    foodCounter += 1
    if foodCounter >= NEWFOOD:
        # add new food
        foodCounter = 0
        foods.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH - 20), random.randint(0, WINDOWHEIGHT - 20), 20, 20))

    baddieCounter += 1
    if baddieCounter >= NEWBADDIE:
        baddieCounter = 0
        baddies.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH - 20), random.randint(0, WINDOWHEIGHT - 20), 20, 20))

    # draw the pink background onto the surface
    windowSurface.fill(PINK)

    # move the player
    if moveDown and player.bottom < WINDOWHEIGHT:
        player.top += MOVESPEED
    if moveUp and player.top > 0:
        player.top -= MOVESPEED
    if moveLeft and player.left > 0:
        player.left -= MOVESPEED
    if moveRight and player.right < WINDOWWIDTH:
        player.right += MOVESPEED
    drawText('Score: %s' % (Score), font, windowSurface, 10,0)

    # draw the block onto the surface
    windowSurface.blit(playerStretchedImage, player)

    # check if the block has intersected with any food squares.
    for food in foods[:]:
        if player.colliderect(food):
            foods.remove(food)
            Score+=2
            if musicPlaying:
                pickUpSound.play()

    for baddie in baddies[:]:
        if player.colliderect(baddie):
            baddies.remove(baddie)
            Score-=4
            if musicPlaying:
                pickUpSound.play()

    if Score < 0:
        drawText('You have lost', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
        drawText('Press escape to quit the game', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 50, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
        drawText('Press any other key to play again', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 50, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 100)
        pygame.display.update()
        waitForPlayerToPressKey()




    # draw the food
    for food in foods:
        windowSurface.blit(foodImage, food)

    # draw the baddie
    for baddie in baddies:
        windowSurface.blit(baddieImage, baddie)

    # draw the window onto the screen
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(40)



if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

The game is simple. The player moves around, collects food to get points and avoids baddies so they don't lose points. When the score drops below 0, the player loses. I managed to get and end game screen, but I can't make it play again or quit the game after this point.

Answer (score 1):

First of, one **suggestion**. People will be more likely to help you if you show them what you've tried.

anyhow.

What I would do is wrap your entire game loop in a function. Like so:

```
def game_loop():
    while True:
    # check for the QUIT event
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
            ....
```

next when ever your game ends(I'm assuming it does have a condition that makes it end), call a game over screen function. In your game over screen function, you could first fill the window with a color, then blit any text to the screen you wan to show the user, such as "Press any key to play again". Then you would check if any key was pressed and if so call the game loop function. You also need to check if the user is trying to close the window.

Then call the game over screen function like so:

```
#pseudo code
if game_has_ended == True:
   game_over_screen()
```

Comment: Yo, how's it going. Your graph shows you've been killing it recently :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks man, I've trying to up my game :) I feel like I could be doing better though. I've been seeing using the dupe hammer lately and I've been feeling sorta jealous...I'm using it as motivation though to keep pushing harder ;-)

Comment: A small confession... 10k isn't as glam as I thought it'd be. Don't be _too_ disappointed. The dupe hammer is fun though. :) Btw, the python tag is really cutthroat. In contrast, the pandas tag is a lot more welcoming.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Tell me about it. I love answering questions in the Python tag just as much as the next Pythonista, but I've just had to take a break sometimes and work on a project or something. The pygame tag however was much easier to transition into, which is why many of my first answers here on the site are in that tag. You're right though. I've never really been into pandas, numpy, or scientific libraries in general. But I've been trying them out lately, and the more I use them, the more I'm getting hooked. Expect to start seeing more competition in the pandas tag in a few more weeks ;-)

Comment: Word of advice... don't answer questions when jezrael is online. Your self confidence will plummet. x(

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Ha, thanks for the tip :-) I guess it's sorta the same way with Martijn Pieters and python-internal questions ;-)